# Error executing stored procedure returning Entity

Tags: c#, model, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to run a stored procedure that returns an entity model using EF 5.0

When the procedure is executed, I get this error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the 'SCTVModel.Cidades'
>   specified. A member of type 'NrSeqCidade' does not have a
>   corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

My C# code:

```
public IEnumerable<Cidades> GetByUf(string uf)
{
    _context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    return _context.GetCidadesByUf(uf);
}

public ObjectResult<Cidades> GetCidadesByUf(global::System.String uF)
{
    ObjectParameter uFParameter;
    if (uF != null)
    {
        uFParameter = new ObjectParameter("UF", uF);
    }
    else
    {
        uFParameter = new ObjectParameter("UF", typeof(global::System.String));
    }

    return base.ExecuteFunction<Cidades>("GetCidadesByUf", uFParameter);
}
```

I think this error is happening because NrSeqCidade renamed the column in the model.

My stored procedure works fine when I call it from the database engine. When I call the function import returning a Complex Type, it works fine

Does EF have problems when returning an entity with renamed columns of the stored procedure?

Comment: Please provide the C# code you have. Is your Stored Procedure works if you call from database engine?

Comment: My store procedure works fine when I call from database engine.
when I call the function import returning a Complex Type, it works fine.

Comment: do you have "NrSeqCidade" property in your C# class? and do you have that field in database table?